# How to calculate optimum numbers to use in a percentage problem in php

Tags: php, math

I want to use php to randomly generate 'nice numbers' for percentage problems aimed at children. Number 1 is the percentage and Number 2 is the total number. I have been attempting to do this but the execution is longer than 60 seconds. Is it possible to do the calculation and generation of nice numbers (where it finds / checks if is in an integer)?

This is for a plesk server, running MYSQL and PHP. I've tried checking the number of combinations of visual basic (there are 622) and it takes 0.4632853 seconds to complete.

```
 function genRandomNumber(){
    return (rand(5, 200));
    }
function genRandomPercent(){
    return (rand(5, 75));
    }
$number1 = genRandomPercent();
$number2 = genRandomNumber();
if (is_int(($number1/100)*$number2)==false){ 
    while (is_int(($number1/100)*$number2)==false) {
        $number1 = genRandomPercent();
        $number2 = genRandomNumber();
    }
}
```

I expect the final output to have number1 and number2 where number1% of number2 is an integer. For example, number1 = 10 and number2 = 60, so 10% of 60 which is 6. Instead, I get an error message of 'PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded'

Comment: It's because your while loop is in infinite condition? How many time you want to run the while loop?

Comment: There are better ways of doing what you want to achieve than randomly picking numbers until you get a match. You can randomly select a number at first, create an array of the percentages that, when multiplied by the number, create integers, and then choose randomly from that array.

Comment: is_int tells you if the variable Is of type int. That Is not the same as asking if floating point number actualy represents an integer. 10 Is type int, 10.0 Is type float. Yet they both represent integer in the mathematical sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to test all combinations with 2 loops. To compare float values must work with eps.

```
<?php
$percentStart = 5;
$percentEnd = 75;
$numberStart = 5;
$numberEnd = 200;
$eps = 1.E-9;
$results=[];
for($percent = $percentStart; $percent <= $percentEnd; $percent++){
  for($number = $numberStart; $number <= $numberEnd; $number++){
    $percentFromNumber = $percent * $number/100;
    if(fmod($percentFromNumber,1) < $eps){
      $results[] = [
        'percent' => $percent,
        'number'  => $number,
        '%number' => $percentFromNumber
      ];
    }
  }
}
var_dump($results);
```

Checking the number of combinations with this code (there are 620!) and it takes 3 milliseconds seconds to complete.